# Why did my bacon smell and taste like beef?

Tags: food-safety, flavor, bacon, smell, standards

I made a bacon sandwich earlier and while cooking the bacon I noticed a pungent scent identical to the scent of beef crisps, I then ate my sandwich which tasted like a mix of beef and smokey bacon crisps.

Comment: Sorry...this is just impossible to answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what beef crisps smell like, but if it's a pungent smell, maybe that's not good. I will tell you that the flavor of the meat comes mostly from the fat, so if you're cooking in beef fat, even if it's pork, it will taste of beef, and vice-versa.